# snake game will fail when rapidly press three buttons once

Tags: python, pygame

Currently I'm using pygame to create my first snake game, but there is a weird bug exist. When I press three bottoms, such as up+left+right, simultaneously, my game will automatically be stopped. Python might think the snake collide its own body, so it lets the game stop, but actually the snake doesn't.

I don't know how can I fix this.

This is my code:

```
from all_class_and_setting import *


def main():
    interaction = Interaction()
    moved_snake = pygame.USEREVENT
    # slow down the while loop into 120 ms per cycle
    pygame.time.set_timer(moved_snake, 120)
    while True:
        display.fill((175, 215, 70))
        interaction.fruit.create_fruit()
        interaction.snake.create_snake()
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            if event.type == moved_snake:
                interaction.snake_moved()
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_w:
                    if interaction.snake.direction.y != 1:
                        interaction.snake.direction = Vector2(0, -1)
                if event.key == pygame.K_s:
                    if interaction.snake.direction.y != -1:
                        interaction.snake.direction = Vector2(0, 1)
                if event.key == pygame.K_a:
                    if interaction.snake.direction.x != 1:
                        interaction.snake.direction = Vector2(-1, 0)
                if event.key == pygame.K_d:
                    if interaction.snake.direction.x != -1:
                        interaction.snake.direction = Vector2(1, 0)
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                # change snake moving direction if snake is not moving in opposite of the changed direction
                if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    if interaction.snake.direction.y != 1:
                        interaction.snake.direction = Vector2(0, -1)
                if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    if interaction.snake.direction.y != -1:
                        interaction.snake.direction = Vector2(0, 1)
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    if interaction.snake.direction.x != 1:
                        interaction.snake.direction = Vector2(-1, 0)
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    if interaction.snake.direction.x != -1:
                        interaction.snake.direction = Vector2(1, 0)
        pygame.display.update()
        run_speed.tick(60)


main()
```

This is all the classes and variables I created:

```
import pygame
import random
import sys
from pygame.math import Vector2

pygame.init()
pygame.display.set_caption("CS150_Final_Project:Snake")
run_speed = pygame.time.Clock()
cell_size = 40
cell_number = 20
display = pygame.display.set_mode((cell_size * cell_number, cell_size * cell_number))
apple = pygame.image.load("Snake-main/apple.png").convert_alpha()

class Fruit:
    """

    """

    def __init__(self):
        # create an x and y position
        self.x = random.randint(0, cell_number - 1)
        self.y = random.randint(0, cell_number - 1)
        self.pos = Vector2(self.x, self.y)

    def create_fruit(self):
        fruit_rect = pygame.Rect(int(self.pos.x * cell_size), int(self.pos.y * cell_size),cell_size,cell_size)
        display.blit(apple,fruit_rect)
        #pygame.draw.rect(display, (98, 166, 140), fruit_rect)

    def new_fruit(self):
        self.x = random.randint(0, cell_number - 1)
        self.y = random.randint(0, cell_number - 1)
        self.pos = Vector2(self.x, self.y)


class Snake:
    def __init__(self):
        # treat snake as different position vectors
        self.body = [Vector2(3, 2), Vector2(2, 2), Vector2(1, 2)]
        self.direction = Vector2(1, 0)

    def create_snake(self):
        for body in self.body:
            x_pos = int(body.x * cell_size)
            y_pos = int(body.y * cell_size)
            snake = pygame.Rect(x_pos, y_pos, cell_size, cell_size)
            pygame.draw.rect(display, (0, 150, 232), snake)

    def move_snake(self):
        """
        change self.body into body_copy

        SNAKE -> None

        """
        # add new position vectors into the list's index zero as the head of the snake
        body_copy = self.body[:-1]
        body_copy.insert(0, body_copy[0] + self.direction)
        self.body = body_copy

    def add_length(self):
        body_copy = self.body[:]
        body_copy.insert(0, body_copy[0] + self.direction)
        self.body = body_copy


class Interaction:
    def __init__(self):
        self.snake = Snake()
        self.fruit = Fruit()

    def snake_moved(self):
        self.snake.move_snake()
        self.collision()
        self.death()

    def collision(self):
        if self.snake.body[0] == self.fruit.pos:
            self.fruit.new_fruit()
            self.snake.add_length()

    def death(self):
        if not 0 <= self.snake.body[0].x < cell_number or not 0 <= self.snake.body[0].y < cell_number:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        for block in self.snake.body[1:]:
            if block == self.snake.body[0]:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that more than on `KEYDOWN` has be handled in on frame. Do not change `interaction.snake.direction` in the event loop, but set a local variable with the new direction and update `interaction.snake.direction` after the event loop:

```py
new_direction = interaction.snake.direction

for event in pygame.event.get():
    # [...]

    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_w or event.key == pygame.K_UP:
            if interaction.snake.direction.y != 1:
                new_direction = Vector2(0, -1)
        if event.key == pygame.K_s or event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
            if interaction.snake.direction.y != -1:
                new_direction = Vector2(0, 1)
        if event.key == pygame.K_a or event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
            if interaction.snake.direction.x != 1:
                new_direction = Vector2(-1, 0)
        if event.key == pygame.K_d or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            if interaction.snake.direction.x != -1:
                new_direction = Vector2(1, 0)

interaction.snake.direction = new_direction
```

Comment: sorry, but the problem is not solved. The bug is still existed.